# html5- convert mp4 video to other formats programmatically

Tags: php, html5-video

how to convert mp4 format video files to other formats like .ogg and .webm to run in all browsers during upload using php and jquery. And is there any solution to use encode one format to other formats according to browser's need so that it will occupy less space on server.

Comment: I'm surprised that disk space is a bigger concern then the CPU time needed to re-encode videos on demand in real time.

Comment: @Quentin yes u r right.

Comment: If you just want to show mp4 videos consistently through different (modern) browsers and devices, you may want to check http://www.picssel.com/play-mp4-videos-with-mediaelement-js-in-fancybox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have multiple files to use with HTML5 for browser compatibility, use FFMpeg to do the conversions on file upload.

http://ffmpeg.org

If you want to just use one mp4 file and have a flash fallback for all browsers, I would recommend MediaElement.js.

http://mediaelementjs.com

Comment: i think media element is a good option. Thanks @Thomas

Comment: please tell me can we use mediaelement.js for commercial use?

Comment: @user3456241 Yes, the license says GPLv2/MIT, so you can use it commercially.